# Showing extra contents at the bottom of my web page where I called paypal sandbox api

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I used paypal sandbox call in my page 3 times. When the page loads it looks ok. But unfortunately at the last time it loads some texts like the following 3 times as called the pai 3 times in my code.

- About to connect() to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0) * Trying 173.0.82.83... * connected * Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0) * SSL connection using AES256-SHA * Server certificate: * subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com * start date: 2011-08-11 00:00:00 GMT * expire date: 2013-09-17 23:59:59 GMT * issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3 * SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway. > POST /nvp HTTP/1.1 Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com Accept: */* Content-Length: 899 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2013 23:55:08 GMT < Server: Apache < Content-Length: 412 < Connection: close < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 < * Closing connection #0

Luckily it was ok when I run the same code from my localhost. After uploading it to a server it looks like this.

**How to get rid of this?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with PHP?  It looks like something that would happen if you're displaying the post headers with your CURL request.  Try adding the following to your CURL code...

```
curl_setopt('CURLOPT_HEADER',TRUE);
```

If you're not using PHP then there should be something similar in whatever method you're using to POST the data to PayPal.

Comment: Sorry Bro. I found the solution though. I had to use curl_setopt('CURLOPT_VERBOSE',FALSE). Earlier I was trying with 'TRUE'. It silly, I know.